# $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)=0\text{ and }\Re(z)\ge 0\}$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I want to show that if $$f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\Im(z)=0\text{ and }\Re(z)\ge 0\}$$ is holomorphic, then f is constant.

I tried to show that $f$ is bounded, then I can use Liouville's theorem.

Is this the right way and how can I see that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: What about the Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: Did you see little Picard's theorem ? (Maybe a bulldozer to kill this problem)

Comment: I do not know this theorem so I am not allowed to use it :/ How does the Riemann mapping theorem helps?

Comment: The Riemann mapping theorem implies that the codomain of your map is biholomorphic with a unit disc. Hence you can apply Liouville's theorem.

Comment: why not just write $\mathbb C \setminus [0,\infty).$

Comment: Merci for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint- you have a holomorphic branch of the logarithm in the given region. Now compose maps.

Alternatively, use the square root function to map the slit plane to the upper half plane, and then use the standard transformation that takes the UHP to the unit disk.

Comment: Yes, I can compose $\log\circ f$, since $\log:\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and the composition is well-defined. In which way does this help? If I know that $\log$ is bounded, then $\log\circ f$ is constant and since $\log$ is bijective, $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Log is not bounded, but rather maps to an infinite strip. Now can you find a bounded function on an infinite strip?

Answer (score 1):

The function $-f$ does not assume nonpositive real values, hence the principal value $g:={\rm pv}\sqrt{-f}$ is well defined. The values of $g$ lie in the right half-plane, and this implies that the entire function $h:=e^{-g}$ is bounded. By Liouville's theorem therefore all three functions $h$, $g$, and $f$ are constant.

Comment: It directly follows from Picard's little theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Use [Picard's little theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PicardsLittleTheorem.html).

$f$ is entire and it omits all non-negative real numbers.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of the exercise.