# Entire $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty) $ is constant (no Picard)

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Entire $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty) $ is constant (no Picard)

---

my first idea was to consider some transformation $\bigg(g=(-f-1)/(-f+1), e^{f}+1/e^f ,\text{etc}\bigg)  $ and use Liouville's theorem, but I couldn't make it work.

Then I thought to consider an entire $g$ (in relation to $f$) and extend the image from $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty)$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ which is not connected so $g$ has to be constant,

I tried $g=\begin{cases}
f(z) & \text{ if } z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus D(0,1) \\ 
 \overline{f(\overline{z})}& \text{ if } z\in D(0,1) 
\end{cases}$

but I not so sure if this is correct, can someone verify ?

Comment: $\arg \log f$ is a bounded harmonic function so is constant by Liouville (or if you want equivalently$e^{i\log f}$ is bounded entire hence constant)

Comment: @Conrad thanks for the quick solution, is my approach wrong thought ?

Comment: @Conrad also you mean $-f$ ? In case of $Log $ but you didn't specify

Comment: Two non-Picard solutions here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1858478/42969

Comment: @MartinR Again, thanks for the solutions, but I spend quite some time working on that problem and I want to know if my method is correct or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see at all how your solution works. Why should $g$ be holomorphic? And even it it where holomorphic, why should $g$ be constant?

Comment: @MartinR If $g$ is entire, then $g(\mathbb{C})$ is not connected, and it follows that $g$ is constant

Comment: Your reasoning seems circular. You give a definition of the function $g$, whether it is entire or not follows from the definition. Why is the function $g$ entire based on the way you define it?

Comment: @user1046533 isn't $g$ homomorphic in every branch ?

Comment: How do you prove the holomorphicity of $g$ on the boundary $|z|=1$?

Comment: @user1046533 probably I can't, I thought I could change Schwarz reflection principle to make it work.

Comment: This approach seems to have some problems... Instead, how about finding a conformal map from the slit plane to the disk... and invoke Liouville, as you say? (First rotate to put the slit on the negative axis, then take square root to get a half-plane, then use some form of "Cayley map" to map the half-plane to a disk.)

Comment: @paulgarrett: ... that is essentially what the solutions in the above-referenced Q&A do.

Comment: @lupusnox: $g$ would only be holomorphic if $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ on the boundary of the unit disk, and that is not given. And even if $g$ were holomorphic, it is still a map from $\Bbb C$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty)$, so you have not gained anything. – Composing $f$ with a square root or logarithm (as in the referenced Q&A) *is* the way to go here.

Comment: @Conrad arg is not entire function

Comment: If the image of $f$ is included in a simply connected domain not containing zero, $\arg f$ is a bounded harmonic function and Liouville is valid for those as one see by taking $g=u+iv$ holomorphic and then $e^g$ is bounded if $u$ bounded - in this case one can take $g=e^{i\log f}$ which is entire bounded